# googleBigQuery: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient::runQuery()

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am stuck with this error, let me know if there is any workarounds:

> `googleBigQuery: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to`
>
> `Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient::runQuery() must be an instance`
>
> `of Google\Cloud\BigQuery\JobConfigurationInterface, string given`

Code sample:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

// get the project ID as the first argument    
$projectId = 'bigquery-public-data';

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);

$query = 'SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as unique_words ' .
         'FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare]';
         
$options = ['useLegacySql' => true];
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($query, $options);

if ($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    $i = 0;
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        printf('--- Row %s ---' . PHP_EOL, ++$i);
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $column, $value);
        }
    }
    printf('Found %s row(s)' . PHP_EOL, $i);
} else {
    throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
}
```

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Resolved by using below code..

<?php
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;


// Authenticate using a keyfile path
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => 'keyfile.json'
]);

$bigQuery = $cloud->bigQuery();

//$query = 'SELECT commit FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` WHERE message = ? LIMIT 100';

$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query)
    ->parameters(['A commit message.']);
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($queryJobConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting for you a full example as this is much more easier.

You need to setup the service account default credentials see lines with `putenv` and `useApplicationDefaultCredentials()`. This is a working code I have using the library https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php

You need to obtain your service account key file from the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.13.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

**php file**

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;

$query="SELECT repository_url, 
       repository_has_downloads 
FROM   [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
LIMIT  10";
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__) . '/.ssh/dummyname-7f0004z148e1.json');//this can be created with other ENV mode server side
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$builder = new ServiceBuilder([
                'projectId' => 'edited',
        ]);

        $bigQuery = $builder->bigQuery();

        $job = $bigQuery->runQueryAsJob($query);
        $info=$job->info();
//      print_r($info);
//      exit;
        $queryResults = $job->queryResults();

        /*$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery(
            $query,
            ['useLegacySql' => true]);*/

        if ($queryResults->isComplete()) 
        {
            $i = 0;
            $rows = $queryResults->rows();

            foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {
                $i++;

                $result[$i] = $row;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
        }

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi @Pentium10, I tried above code but getting different error "Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gbq-test\google-api-php-client-master\sample-bigquery.php on line 9"..

Comment: you need to have the correct composer.json applied and included

Comment: I had actually downloaded the library files from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and changed the composer file as you suggested.. can you suggest any workaround..

Comment: that library is no longer maintained, make sure you are not confused, there are two libraries https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php composer.json file references  `"google/cloud": "^0.13.0"`

Comment: Could you plz share the folder listing from your library i tried with github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php too, but dint help..